# Decoding (JSON) HttpWebResponse in C#

Tags: c#, json

Here is my code:

```
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
var vrati = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObjectAsync(responseString);
log.Text = vrati["f"][0];
```

I'm using **Newtonsoft**.Json.JsonConvert and I don't know how to go.

JSON Code is like

```
{"a":13,"o":215,"f":["g","i"]}
```

**And I want to get ["f"][0] .. "g" in my sample.** Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something dynamic, quick and dirty you could just:

```
var dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>("{\"a\":13,\"o\":215,\"f\":[\"g\",\"i\"]}");

    Console.WriteLine(dynJson.a);
    Console.WriteLine(dynJson.o);

    foreach(var something in dynJson.f){
        Console.WriteLine(something);
    }
```

If you want something typed you can create an object that matches your Json and Deserialize:

```
    void Main()
{
    var dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyThing>("{\"a\":13,\"o\":215,\"f\":[\"g\",\"i\"]}");

    Console.WriteLine(dynJson.a);
    Console.WriteLine(dynJson.o);
    foreach(var something in dynJson.f){
        Console.WriteLine(something);
    }
}

public class MyThing {

    public int a {get;set;}
    public int o {get;set;}
    public List<string> f {get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using dynamics

```
string responseString = "{\"a\":13,\"o\":215,\"f\":[\"g\",\"i\"]}";
dynamic vrati = JObject.Parse(responseString);

log.Text = vrati["f"][0];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse it into a dynamic object:

```
string data = "{\"a\":13,\"o\":215,\"f\":[\"g\",\"i\"]}";
dynamic obj = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);
string result = obj.f[0].Value;
```